# Making unique slug url in Oracle

Tags: regex, oracle, slug

I am trying to make unique slug URL in oracle using with regular expression.  How can I get numeric value end of URL like that `lorem-ipsum-dolor-2`.  My purpose that; Before I check inserted title if exist on table, check it numeric value end of URL if exist slug URL, if has numeric value increase it and save.  I have tried the following regular expression that worked properly in C# but it not work in Oracle.

```
select regexp_like('lorem-ipsum-dolor-2','(\d+)*$') from dual;
```

Comment: In the database table, separate the two portions of the slug into separate columns, the second column being a `number` type. Then you can just add one to it. Put a unique constraint on the two columns, and you're done.

Comment: read up on regexp_like http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/regexp_like.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is almost correct.

But instead of `regexp_like' you need to use`regexp_substr`:sp

```
select regexp_substr('lorem-ipsum-dolor-2','\d+$') from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using oracle APEX, and I can assume that's the case if you are working with URLs, than you can use

```
select apex_string_util.to_slug('Any, Text!;')  from dual;
>>  any-text
```